# How to multiply -1 with BigDecimal

Tags: bigdecimal

In Java, I have a big decimal number , I want to multiply with -1.

```
BigDecimal amount, total;
total = amount*-1;
```

If i give like this, it is throwing error upfront. How can I multiply -1 with bigdecimal number.

Comment: This seems like a really basic question about BigDecimal. Have you read a tutorial? Some documentation?

Comment: Operator * is undefined for the argument  types BigDecimal,int

Comment: I think i have to use Bigdecimal.multiply(amount.multiply) ...but dont know how to multiply with -1

Comment: Then how about `total = amount * new BigDecimal(-1);` ?  Or just `total = amount.negate();`. Note that you should initialize `amount` first.

Answer (score 4):

When you work with BigDecimals you need to work with the class functions.

```
BigDecimal total, minus;
total = new BigDecimal(1);
minus = new BigDecimal(-1);
System.out.println(total);
System.out.println(total.multiply(minus));
```

But to keep it very simple you can just use a function for this:

```
BigDecimal total;
total = new BigDecimal(1);
System.out.println(total.negate());
```

For more details check this link:
http://intra.csb.ethz.ch/javadoc/metabolic/ch/javasoft/math/NumberOperations.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use negate() function and the BigDecimal constants :)

```
BigDecimal total = amount.multiply(BigDecimal.ONE.negate());
```